How can I clean a year column with messy values?
I have a project I'm working on for a data analysis course, where we pick a data set and go through the steps of cleaning and exploring the data with a question to answer in mind.
I want to be able to see how many instances of the data occur in different years, but right now the Year column in the data set is set to a datatype object, with values spanning from whole years like 1998, just the last 2 digits like 87, ranges of presumed years ('early 1990's', '89 or 90', '2011- 2012', 'approx 2001').
I'm trying to determine the best way to convert all these various instances to the proper format or would it be better to drop the values that are not definitive? I worry that this would lead to too much data loss because the dataset is already pretty small (about 5000 rows total).
I have looked into regex and it seems like that is the path I should go down to keep and alter the values, but I still don't understand it conceptually very well, and I worry about the efficiency of filtering for so many different value variations.
I'm still very new to Python and pandas.

Questions must provide a [mcve], input sample, minimal code snippet that reproduces the issue.

Difficult to say what is best without knowing your data and the question that you want to answer but one option I would investigate is to bin the years maybe by group of 3 or 5 years ( ..., 1996-2000, 2001-2005, 2006-2010, ...)

Assuming your Year columns are strings, I would write a normalize function like this:
import re
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"year": "early 1990's"},
    {"year": "89 or 90"},
    {"year": "2011-2012"},
    {"year": "approx 2001"},
]

def normalize(row):
    year = row["year"]

    # Count the number of digits
    count = len(re.findall("\\d", year))

    if count == 4:
        # match YYYY
        if m := re.search("\\d\\d\\d\\d", year):
            return m.group(0)

    if count == 2:
        # match YY
        if m := re.search("\\d\\d", year):
            return "19" + m.group(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["normalized"] = df.apply(normalize, axis=1)
print(df)

=>
           year normalized
0  early 1990's       1990
1      89 or 90       None
2     2011-2012       None
3   approx 2001       2001

The function returns None for unmatched pattern.  You can list them as follows:
>>> print(df[df["normalized"].isnull()])
...
        year normalized
1   89 or 90       None
2  2011-2012       None

Review the output and modify the normalize function as you like.  Repeat these steps until you get satisfied.

If I were responsible for analyzing this data, I'd want to explore how much those multi-years value mean to my analysis. I'd also split up the cleaning phase from the analysis phase, I wouldn't try to do two things in one pass. At only 5000 rows, I'd scroll through the cleaned output and see what my eye catches that my year-cleaning code didn't catch.
This pair of regex and parse function normalizes string values from the Year column:
import re

RE_Year = re.compile(r"\d{2}(?:\d{2})?")
"""a 2-digit or 4-digit number"""


def parse_years(s: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    """
    parse_years finds one or two numbers-as-years in s.

    4-digit numbers are taken literally, 2-digit numbers are
    presumed to be from, and converted to, the 20th century,
    ("xx" to "19xx").
    """
    norm = lambda s: "19" + s if len(s) == 2 else s

    match len(years := RE_Year.findall(s)):
        case 1:
            return norm(years[0]), ""
        case 2:
            return norm(years[0]), norm(years[1])
        case _:
            raise ValueError(f'expected one or two year-numbers in "{s}"')

We can see what that does with the samples you provided, and a bad value I added to highlight the error handling:
parse_years("early 1990's"):     ('1990', '')
parse_years("89 or 90"):         ('1989', '1990')
parse_years("2011-2012"):        ('2011', '2012')
parse_years("approx 2001"):      ('2001', '')
parse_years("1997"):             ('1997', '')
parse_years("two-thousand-one"): ValueError: 'expected one or two year-numbers in "two-thousand-one"'

I'd also want to keep the original data close to the new data so I could try to visually compare and see if some insight jumped out to me.
The following:

reads the input CSV row-by-row
adds two more columns, Year1 and Year2
tries to parse the Year column and fill the new columns
writes to an output CSV

Any errors are printed and the row has two blank strings added for Year1 and Year2:
import csv

def add_years(year1: str, year2: str, row: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    """
    add_years adds year1 and year2 in row, after the "Year" column
    (index 1).
    """
    return row[:2] + [year1, year2] + row[2:]


with (
    open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in,
    open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out,
):
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    header = next(reader)
    writer.writerow(add_years("Year1", "Year2", header))

    for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        try:
            year1, year2 = parse_years(row[1])
        except Exception as e:
            year1, year2 = "", ""
            print(f"could not parse Year column in row {i}: {e}")

        writer.writerow(add_years(year1, year2, row))

Running all that on this input CSV:
Color,  Year
red,    early 1990's
blue,   89 or 90
green,  2011-2012
yellow, approx 2001
purple, 1997
orange, two-thousand-one

I get this output CSV:
Color,  Year,             Year1, Year2
red,    early 1990's,     1990,
blue,   89 or 90,         1989,  1990
green,  2011-2012,        2011,  2012
yellow, approx 2001,      2001,
purple, 1997,             1997,
orange, two-thousand-one, ,

and this error printed in the console:
could not parse Year column in row 6: expected one or two year-numbers in "two-thousand-one"

I added the pretty-printed columns above for clarity.
